# Field $K (x)$ of rational functions with coefficients from $K$, if $f\in K(x)$, then $f^2 \neq x^2-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I'm in the process of studying for an exam and I came across the following question:

> Prove that if $K$ is a field and $K (x)$ is the field of rational functions with coefficients from $K$, if $f\in K(x)$, then $f^2 \neq  x^2-1$.

In trying to solve this I think I came up with a contradiction.

The counterexample I came up with is the following: let $K = \Bbb Z_2$ then if $f= x+1$, $f^2=(x+1)^2$, so in $\Bbb Z_2[x], (x+1)^2= x^2 +2x+1= x^2+1= x^2-1$.

Any help with why my counterexample does not work or how to prove this  would be much appreciated.

Edit: fixed a typo above, $f$ should be from the field of polynomials.

Comment: sorry, $f$ should be from the field of polynomials, not the field itself.

Comment: I edited your question to correct this. Does it look good now?

Comment: yes thanks, im still getting used to the site your edit beat mine :)

Comment: Your counterexample works. If this is indeed how the question is presented, then it's incorrect.

Comment: Thanks! now at least I know i'm not going crazy

Comment: They might've snuck in a $\operatorname{char}(K)\neq 2$ somewhere, though.

Comment: @Arthur that is probably what they were going for, but after my first typo I reread the question to make sure I wrote it down verbatim. If it had that $char(K)≠2$, then my strategy of using the general derivative to show $f^2$ has a repeated root would work. Thanks for taking a look anyway!

Comment: @WillS. In the end it's not clear if $f$ is a polynomial (as your comments seem to assume) or a rational fraction (as the notation $K(x)$ suggests), which seems to me more likely.

Comment: @user26857 Yes, I was being imprecise with my language and probably not thinking about the problem the right way, but does $f$ being a rational function affect the counterexample I came up with or make the statement true even for a field of characteristic 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $f=\frac{Q}{P}$ where $P,Q\in\mathbb{K}[x]$ and $\gcd(Q,P)=1$. Assuming that $f^2=(x-1)(x+1)$ we get : $$Q^2=(x-1)(x+1)P^2 \qquad (*).$$ Let us work in $\mathbb{K}[x]$. You see that the prime $(x-1)$ divides $Q^2$. So $x-1$ divides $Q$ but not $P$ $(\gcd(Q,P)=1)$. Writing $Q=(x-1)Q_1$, and using $(*)$ we have :
$$(x-1)Q_1^2=(x+1)P^2.$$ 
This leads to a condradiction if $\mathrm{Char}(\mathbb{K}) \neq 2$, since $x-1$ divides neither $P^2$ neither $x+1$. Therefore $f^2\neq (x-1)(x+1)$.

Generally, if $p$ is a prime and $b$ is a square then $\max\{k \mid p^k  \text{ divides }  b\}$ is even.

Comment: This is a good strategy to use, but in the end it still fails if $K= \Bbb Z_2$. I'll have to remember this idea though, thanks.

Comment: It fails since the statemant is not true for $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Indeed in $char=2$, we have $x+1=x-1$ therfore $(x-1)(x+1)$ is a square....

Answer (score 0):

In the $char(K) \neq 2$-case, this is literally the same question as asking to show $\sqrt{6} \notin \mathbb Q$. In an UFD an element is a square in the fraction field if and only if all exponents appearing in the unique factorization are even. The critical argument is that an UFD is integrally closed in its fraction field.